# c program finding call function

Tags: c, algorithm

Two integers are stored in the arrays a 1 and a 2, respectively, and the product is calculated by the same procedure as the calculation, but it does not output the correct result.
question is : want to produce 312*321 = 1 0 0 1 5 2 but this first program produce 
? 0 9 9 11 5 2
to produce right result 1 0 0 1 5 2, call function name func(c,N*2)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 3
int main()
 {

 int a1[N]={1,2,3};
 int a2[N]={2,1,3};
 int b[N][N];
 int c[N*2];
 int i,j;

 for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=0;j<N;j++)
b[i][j]=a1[j]*a2[i];
 }


 c[0]=b[0][0];
 c[1]=b[0][1]+b[1][0];
 c[2]=b[0][2]+b[1][1]+b[2][0];
 c[3]=b[1][2]+b[2][1];
 c[4]=b[2][2];

 for(i=N*2-1;i>=0;i--)
 {
     printf("%d ",c[i]);
 }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The result:0 9 9 11 5 2

```
     　 |0|１|2| ->A1
  ----------------
A2<-| 0|2|４|6|     
    | 1|1|2|3| 
    | 2|3|6|9|
```

this array is the same as 321*312 calculate using hand in paper

Problem: Define the function func () to output the correct result  1 0 0 1 5 2, call func (c, N * 2); below i post the code with the call function func() in bold. any idea?? and also what the logic behind func()? trial and error? is there algorithm behind this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 3
int main()
 {

 int a1[N]={1,2,3};
 int a2[N]={2,1,3};
 int b[N][N];
 int c[N*2];
 int i,j;

 for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=0;j<N;j++)
b[i][j]=a1[j]*a2[i];
 }


 c[0]=b[0][0];
 c[1]=b[0][1]+b[1][0];
 c[2]=b[0][2]+b[1][1]+b[2][0];
 c[3]=b[1][2]+b[2][1];
 c[4]=b[2][2];

 **func(c,N*2);**

 for(i=N*2-1;i>=0;i--)
 {
     printf("%d ",c[i]);
 }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

**void func(int a[],int digit)
{
   here no idea....
    }**
```

Comment: It would seem you're supposed to modify the array passed in so you get the right result when you print the values. I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you're trying to do though.

Comment: here the c array has 0 9 9 11 5 2 result, but since i have to call func function to produce 1 0 0 1 5 2, i can only modified the c array, since it is the only array that passed to the func function. but i dont know how to modify it, dont get the logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this;

```
void func(int a[], int digit)
{
    int i, c = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < digit; i ++)
    {
        a[i] += c;
        c = a[i] / 10;
        a[i] = a[i] % 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou!!!! Can i ask what the logic behind this????? How can you know that you have to divide by 10 and find the remainder? I know here everytime the number bigger than 9 there is a carry in digit but i dont understand how to make program to produce that

Comment: Change the logic: "If the number is bigger than 9 there is a carry" -> "There is always carry even 0". It will make it easy.

Comment: Is the pattern here is when 2 carry is 0, when 5 carry is 0, when 11 carry is 1 and only show last digit so 11%10 is 1, when 9 -> 9+1(carry) so carry is 1 but want to show last digit so 10%10 is 0 ,,,.. so here is the logic????

Comment: And also is this problem so easy for you(?) i mean why is it hard to understand... and also to interpret it to programming language really takes time, and when you dont know the order the result will be different

Comment: Many people are only taught to do arithmetic operations by rote actions and never learned the basic principles behind them. That makes the problem much harder. A good exercise is to figure out how +-*/ work in other than base 10. A good book on set theory through advanced algebra if you really want to get into it.

Comment: I mean like i just realize that the array here also produce by 10^i*10^j here so c is i+j, i mean is this coincidence? Like did you realize that the array is pointing that after or before you make the program(?)(?)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change two things:

First initialization the result array

```
int c[N * 2] = {0}; //initialize
```

Also the function looks like

```
void func(int a[], int size) {
    int carry = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        a[i] += carry;
        carry = a[i] / 10;
        a[i] = a[i] % 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou here why need to initialize c? Besides that do you find the pattarn from the carry?

Comment: @DevinaMuljono Otherwise, `a[5]` will have random initial int value, and have to be dealt with specifically .

Comment: Ah okay i got it since c[5] dont have value. Besides that for c[0]=b[0][0].... is there another way to write it in loop? In order to write it in loop you have to find pattern too?

Comment: And btw in this code, the function of the array is only to show the calculation of number by hand? Successive power of 10(?)(?)